# When window state is maximized then the window is behind the taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windowstate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Borderless application on maximize is hiding behind the task bar in Win 7 and Win 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712035/borderless-application-on-maximize-is-hiding-behind-the-task-bar-in-win-7-and-wi)

my windowstyle is none and I maximized the window the window is behind the task bar and 
I cannot see the while window properly.
i tries this but it doesn't work:

```
this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2584487/1253747

Answer (score 0):

Something you could start with:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(string lpszClassName, string lpszWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    public void WindowsToolbar(bool visible)
    {
        int hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
        ShowWindow(hWnd, visible ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
    }

    public void HideTaskBarIfNeeded(Form form)
    {
        if (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Equals(Screen.FromRectangle(Screen.GetBounds(form))))
        {
            WindowsToolbar(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u but i think u didnt understand what i mean.I need to do this without hiding the taskbar.